# Find number not found in other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have this excel formula which looks for items that are not found in the other column and writes yes or no depending on the result. How can I do the same but using vba in excel?

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B2,$A:$A,0),"yes",),"no")
```

I'm new in vba and excel, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code compares the values in column B to those in column A using the Match function and writes the result (Yes or No) in column C:

```
Sub CompareColumns()

Dim aLastRow As Long
Dim bLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim result As Variant

aLastRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
bLastRow = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To bLastRow

    result = Application.Match(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & aLastRow), 0)

    If IsError(result) Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = "No"
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = "Yes"
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim a As Range, b As Range
    Set a = Range("A:A")
    Set b = Range("B2")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(a, b) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "yes"
    Else
        MsgBox "no"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thx for the fast response, the code does work partially, what im trying to accomplish is to check each value in the column, if im correct this code only compares the 2 columns if they are the same "yes" if not "no" i need to know witch value is not in the other column.